# Prevent code termination in case of an error in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on a python3 code on Windows 10

```
for i in range (len(filenames)):
    line  = filenames[i]
    if os.path.isfile(line.replace('.png','_sgm.npz')):
        disps = np.load(line.replace('.png','_sgm.npz'))
    else:
        disps = SOME RANDOM NUMPY VARIABLE
```

Sometimes the `.npz` file does not exist. So i have inserted that `isfile` clause so that code does not terminate. On rare cases however the `.npz` file exits but `np.load()` gives an error perhaps because the file was corrupted. On such rare cases my code raises an error and code terminates.

How to prevent code termination in case `np.load` fails to load the file? In that case the part after `else` should be executed and code should continue.

Comment: use try, except block ?

Comment: please untag OpenCV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understood your code (I am a beginner) but definitely this is what you want:

```
try:
   print("Hello")#Replace it with the statement(s) where the error can occur
except:
   pass
```

So in your case:

```
for i in range (len(filenames)):
    line  = filenames[i]
    if os.path.isfile(line.replace('.png','_sgm.npz')):
        try:
            disps = np.load(line.replace('.png','_sgm.npz'))
        except:
            pass
    else:
        disps = SOME RANDOM NUMPY VARIABLE
```

Done!

Comment: it is **always** a good idea to catch the exception and print it, like so:`except Exception as e: print(e)`. *never ever* just `except: pass` because that hides problems completely. it is tolerable to catch and ignore *specific* exceptions: `except FileNotFoundError: pass`